# Multiple imputation and regression assumptions

Tags: multiple-regression, assumptions

I have a small data set and I have missing values and decided to use multiple imputation technique

```
id <- mice(df, m=5)
analysis <- with(id, lm(a ~ b + c + d))
summary(pool(analysis))
```

In my model with the missing values the assumptions (normality, linearity, homoscedasticity) are violated how can I check these assumptions even in the 5 data sets? Should I check for each data set? If they are also violated, what method can I use in this case?

Thank you very much for your help!